# Uncertainty in acceleration given two velocities and two times

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, error-analysis

I took a cart on a track and measured the velocity at two positions and the amount of time it took to get from gate 1 to gate 2. I have solved for the uncertainty of the velocity (was specifically told to take the standard deviation of all my results) but am not sure how to get the uncertainty in the acceleration.

For example -

The uncertainty of v1 is 0.005, the uncertainty of v2 is 0.012, the acceleration is 0.483 m/s^2 and the uncertainty in time is a constant 0.0001 as this was the uncertainty in the program used.

How do I combine these to get the uncertainty in my calculated velocity? I know I have to combine these equations but I am absolutely terrible at calculating uncertainty.

[image]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration a is given by: $$a = \frac{v_2-v_1}{t}$$
So you can use your formula for the uncertainty of a product: $$\left(\frac{\delta a}{a}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\delta (v_2-v_1)}{v_2-v_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\delta t}{t}\right)^2$$
and your formula for the uncertainty of a sum to write this: $$(\delta(v_2-v_1))^2 = (\delta v_1)^2+(\delta v_2)^2$$
Combining all this you will obtain the uncertainty on the acceleration $\delta a$